# Incorrect database name connecting to any-db-mysql

Tags: node.js

In a node module using strings, when i write a space (by pressing the space bar) I get :

```
%20
```

And when i write:

```
\n
```

I get:

```
%0A
```

What is happening to spaces in my string? I really need to use spaces.

Does it have something to do with [URL Encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)?

PS: I do not mind putting a strange charter combination to write a space, but i don't want to see %20 in the console.

```
var q=require('any-db-mysql');

q.createConnection('-u my_user -h localhost -D dbname --password[=mypass]',function(e,r){
    cosole.log(e);
    });
```

console.log:

```
Error: ER_WRONG_DB_NAME: Incorrect database name 'u%20my_user%20-h%20localhost%20-D%20dbname%20--password[=mypass]'
```

It has also made '-u' just 'u'..

why?

Comment: Yes exactly. You can use something like `decodeURI()` to decode it.

Comment: Looks like. But you need to be much more specific on *where* you "write" this "in a node module".

Comment: I'm more specific now

Comment: @BENZ.404 this was an example of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). When you post your questions, try to provide as much information as possible — as you can see, now that you've posted the code snippet, it's clear that this has nothing to do with string encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection string should look like this:

```
q.createConnection('mysql://my_user:mypass@localhost/dbname', function (e, r) {
    // ...
});
```

Alternatively, and probably neater, you can use an object:

```
var options = {
    host :    'localhost',
    user:     'my_user',
    password: 'mypass',
    database: 'dbname'
};

q.createConnection(options, function (e, r) { /* ... */ });
```

See https://github.com/grncdr/node-any-db-adapter-spec and https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use decodeURI to get your space

```
var str = "theSpace%20space";
console.log(decodeURI(str));
```